# Azure Cognitive Services - Custom Speech with python and websockets

Tags: python, azure, websocket, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft Custom Speech Services within Python. Currently only with HTTP endpoints.
Accordingly to the documentation, websockets are also supported.

Does any one has an example on sending data through websockets?
I got working so far opening websocket to service with my token. But when I start sending data, the connection closes with error 104.

Details:
- Python3
- websocket-client
- wav with RIFF header (works with HTTP)

thx!

Code sample:

```
# pip install websocket-client
def main_websocket_cris():
    path_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(path_root, 'example_011.wav')
    chunk_size = 8192

    key = '<mykey>'
    url = 'wss://<mydeployment>.api.cris.ai/ws/cris/speech/recognize'
    token = auth_cris(key)

    header = ['Authorization: Bearer %s' % token]
    ws = websocket.create_connection(url, header=header)
    try:
        print('--- send ping')
        ws.ping()
        print('> ping done')

        print('--- send pong')
        ws.pong(b'')
        print('> pong done')

        print('--- status and headers')
        print('> status:',  ws.getstatus())
        print('> headers:', ws.getheaders())
        print('> status done')

        headers = ['Path: audio',
                   'X-RequestId: %s' % str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', ''),
                   'X-Timestamp: %s' % datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
                   'Content-Type: audio/x-wav']
        headers = {
            'Path':         'audio',
            'X-RequestId':  str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', ''),
            'X-Timestamp':  str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()),
            'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav'
        }
        print(headers)
        #ws.send(json.dumps(headers))

        print('--- send binary data')
        print('> read file in chunks of %s bytes' % chunk_size)
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                ws.send(json.dumps(headers))
                ws.send_binary(chunk)
        print("> Sent")
        print('--- now receive answer')
        print("> Receiving...")
        result = ws.recv()
        print("> Received '%s'" % result)
    finally:
        print('--- close')
        ws.close()
        print('> closed')
```

Comment: Hi, would you please post more details about your code and error log to let me help you ?

Comment: code sample added...

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I'm trying and seem to be having very similar issues. I'd appreciate a hand

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the Speech Protocol endpoints (e.g., "wss://YOUR_DEPLOYMENT.api.cris.ai/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1").

The protocol used by these endoints is documented here: [Microsoft Speech WebSocket Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol). You can find a JavaScript implementation of the protocol [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-WebSockets-Javascript).